# Sort based on the smallest occurrence of integers

Tags: elasticsearch

Each document has an array of integers. I need to sort them based on the smallest occurrence of these integers. Do I need to use scripts to employ such a sorting, and if yes how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) with a small groovy script that returns the smallest integer from your array (here named `your_array`).

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc.your_array.values.min()"
    }
  }
}
```

Also make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.